# LL(1) Grammar for XML-like language

Tags: xml, parsing

Consider an LL(1) grammar for a subset of XML, let it be XML without attributes.
I came up with something like this:

```
S -> BLOCK
BLOCK -> PART1 PART2
PART1 -> <NAME
PART2 -> >BODY</NAME> | />
BODY -> BLOCK BODY | EPS
```

Where the nonterminal NAME is a non-empty string of chars.
The problem here is the grammar is not LL(1) because there's ambiguity inside the first production for the nonterminal PART2: after parsing the '>' character, you cannot establish whether the '<' character derives from PART2 itself (that would mean BODY is the empty string EPS) or from the nonterminal PART1 (so BODY is BLOCKBODY and the '<' is obtained from a new block).
The rest of the grammar is OK, and obviously, if I could use different characters to express the '<' used for opening a new tag or closing an existing one, that would do the trick. The bad new is that I can't do that.
My question is: does the LL(1) grammar I'm looking for actually EXIST?
If it does, any ideas on what changes I need to make?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In most practical parsers for XML, "<", ">", "</" and "/>" are all single tokens, and the problem vanishes.  Why can't you do that?

Comment: Ok, I see! How do I do that? I mean, when the parser starts processing '>' within the first production of PART2, should I look ahead TWO characters instead of one? If yes, wouldn't this make the grammar an LL(2) grammar? I'm really puzzled, because IF we consider single tokens, then this grammar IS obviously LL(1). But then again, speaking of raw input scanning, it's kind of considering two characters as one. What am I missing?

Comment: LL(1) doesn't mean lookahead of one character, it means lookahead of one token.  "</" consists of two characters, but can be a single token from the lexer.

Comment: Also see: [Formal grammar of XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814394/formal-grammar-of-xml)